# Problem using C. Program works then acts differently for unknown reason

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, cs50

So in my program I retrieve a command line argument (must be 26 characters with no duplicates) which is used kind of like a rubric for a cypher or something and all these letters are put into an array (i know im not doing it super efficiently).

Following this I prompt for a user to write something and that sentence will in turn change based on what the CLA is inputted as a "cypher" i guess. When i do do this and the cypher is simply just the alphabet (a-z) [therefore should returning the exact same thing written in the prompt] the first couple letters are correct and follow the logic of my code however after getting to the 5th it starts to print out strange random letters for unknown reasons.

ex. hi there how's it going = hi thhrh how's it roisr

plss help :D

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char letters[] = {};
char word[] = {};

// Takes input "Code" and checks if it is suitable (so far) still need to input reminder if no key etc.
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc !=2)
    {
        printf("Missing command-line argument\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else if ((argv[1][1]) == ' ')
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key");
        return 1;
    }
    else if (strlen(argv[1]) != 26)
    {
        printf("Key must contain 26 characters.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); i < n; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(argv[1][i]) != 0)
        {
            letters[i] = argv[1][i];
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Key must only contain alphabetic characters.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (toupper(argv[1][j]) == toupper(argv[1][i]))
            {
                printf("No Repeat Characters\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
    // confirmed this prints the entire focking CLA printf("%c", letters[i]);
    }
    string ptext = get_string("plaintext: ");
    printf("cyphertext: ");

    for (int j = 0; j < strlen(ptext); j++)
    {
         if (ptext[j] >= 'A' && ptext[j] <= 'Z')
         {
            int l = ptext[j] - 65;
            char z = letters[l];
            //printf("%c\n", z);
            word[j] = z;
            printf("%c", word[j]);
         }
         else if (ptext[j] >= 'a' && ptext[j] <= 'z')
         {
            int k = ptext[j] - 97;
            char y = letters[k];
            word[j] = y;
            printf("%c", word[j]);
         }
         else
         {
              printf("%c", ptext[j]);
         }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

thats the code!

I've tried debugging and looking into why the value changes however it just suddenly makes letters[k] not equal to e when it should as it is in the array made earlier in the code. I'm not sure what's happening as im pretty sure the code has sound logic

Comment: What do you think are the sizes of the `letters` and `word` arrays?

Comment: Sorry I dont know how to reply directly its my first time using stack overflow but I'm assuming theyre size 26 for each letter in the alphabet, do you think theyre cutting off early? @dbush . when i do printf after composing the word and letter arrays it gives the entire range all 26 characters so i found that wasn't an issue.

Comment: `char letters[] = {};` is an array of size 0. Accessing any index of it invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Hint: if you don't explicitly specify the length, it's length is the number of initializers.

Comment: really! I didn't know that's how it worked haha thank you guys for the help! really noob at C atm

Comment: @UnholySheep I have doubts the array of size 0 is even valid  C.

Comment: @UnholySheep see the thing is when i did do it that way it worked for the first couple ~5 iterations (hi there how's it going) = (hi thh...)... any idea why? or is that the undefined behavior you're referring to

Comment: `if ((argv[1][1]) == ' ')` makes no sense. This tests if second byte of argv[1] is space. Potential UB too, if strlen(argv [1]) is 0...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you have created zero size arrays

```
char letters[] = {};
char word[] = {};
```

you need to make them larger. I guess you need

```
char letters[26] = {};
char word[50] = {};
```

not quite sure what max size you need tho

Comment: wow thank you so much! i really appreciate it, i didn't know i had to specify I thought the size would increase as I added in values. that being the case do you know why it worked for like the first 5 or so j iterations?

Comment: @Patman nothing happens automatically in C. C++ yes, C , no

Comment: It "worked" for some characters because when you invoke undefined behaviour, literally anything can happen, including it appearing to work. Usually it doesn't.